# Unsetting array elements inside a foreach loop

Tags: php

I have a little problem with arrays. Here is the code:

```
$attributes = array($_SESSION['item_01'] , $_SESSION['item_02'] , $this->item_03 , $this->item_04);
foreach($attributes as $attribute) {
    unset($attribute);
}
```

This code is inside a class and `$this->item_03` and `item_04` is class variables.

So, it doesn't work but when I unset every array element by self (`unset($_SESSION['item_01)` and so on) it works.

Comment: Why unset every element? Unset full array.

Comment: You unset the _copy_ of a value, `$attribute`. That has no effect on the array you copied the values _from_.

Comment: If you read the PHP manual it explains why you can't do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unset by key, not by value.

```
$attributes = array($_SESSION['item_01'] , $_SESSION['item_02'] , $this->item_03 , $this->item_04);
foreach($attributes as $key => $attribute) {
    unset($attributes[$key]);

}
```

if you wish to clear the session object you do:

```
foreach($attributes as $key => $attribute) {
    if(array_key_exists($key, $_SESSION) {
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
        $this->{$key} = null;// this or next line
        unset($this->{$key};
    }
}
```

In php it's enough to 'clear' references to items.

So if you want your memory freed, just set the values to null.

```
$this->item_01 = null;
$this->item_02 = null;
```

then if there are no other references to it, the memory will be freed.

You need to show more of your code if you wish to have a more comprehensive answer.

Comment: ugh, copy fail xD

Comment: define it doesnt works. it will unset the values in the array, which you wanted obviously

Comment: looks like i miss some thing in your answer

Comment: *tries reading @Er.Ellison 's mind* `comes up blank`. What do you mean?